# how to pass id and routing in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

I have a controller in Codeigniter named: `/local/`

My View Page:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>local/<?php echo $id;?>">Business Name</a>
```

when I search anything in this page controller then the function is called:
`local/details` this method

```
function details($ciid){

    $id = $_GET['id'];

   }
```

My Route.php:

```
$route['local/(:num)'] = 'local/details/$ciid';
```

I want to my URL is like `/local/123456789`

But on my page it shows this error:

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Route.php* should be :

```php
$route['local/(:num)'] = 'local/details/$1';
```

And the `details` method should be :

```php
function details($ciid){

    $id = $ciid;

   }
```

Comment: can you please check this problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61006159/change-search-item-url-and-routing-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

```
class Local extends CI_Controller {
   public function details($id){
      //use id
   }

   public function _remap($cid){
      $this->details($cid);       
   }
}
```

Take a look at [Remapping](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#remapping-method-calls)

Also, Make sure that `$cid` is valid and remove route.