# change search item url and routing in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, routes

I want to change the URL with Codeigniter routing:

here is my url:

```
home/search?location=BD

home/search?location=BD&category[]=123

home/search?location=BD&category[]=123&category[]=124&category[]=125
```

like above url but I want to routing this url with

```
home/BD

home/BD/123

home/BD/123+124+125
```

**or**

```
home/BD/123/124/125
```

My *route.php*:

```
$route['home/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'home/search/$1';
```

What is my problem in `route.php` page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use a `(.+)` pattern on your `route.php`, the `$1` will contain the `location` value (`BD`) and the `$2` will contain every parameters past the `home/BD/` url :

```php
$route['home/(:any)/(.+)'] = 'home/search/$1/$2';
```

The `(.+)` pattern is useful if you don't know how many parameters are being passed, it will allow you to capture all of them. And maybe you should use `&` in place of the `+` sign on your url since the `+` sign is probably disallowed by default :

```
home/BD/123&124&125
```

Then you could explode the categories on the controller :

```php
public function search($location = '', $categories = '')
{
    if (!empty($categories)) {
        $categories = explode('&',$categories);
    }
    ...
}
```